# Add loop in argument awk C

Tags: c

I have Shell awk code:

```
awk '{sum+=$10; array[NR,1]=$11; array[NR,2]=$10; next;} END {

  for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    printf "%3.0f'\.' %s \b '\-' %s \b '\-' %3.1f'\%' \n", i, array[i,1], array[i,2], array[i,2]/sum*100
 }'
```

I make program on C:

```
int
main ()
{
    const char *sort[] = { "sort", "-t", " ", "-k", "10", "-r", "-n", "log.txt", 0 };
    const char *head[] = { "head", "-n 10", 0 };
    const char *awk[] = {  "awk", "{sum+=$10; array[NR,1]=$11; array[NR,2]=$10; next;} END { code there }", 0 };

   struct command cmd [] = { {sort}, {head}, {awk} };

  return fork_pipes (3, cmd);
}
```

I dont know how a correct to insert in argument - awk with END { loop code ... }

My task. Add to `const char *awk[] = { "awk", ... }`

```
'{sum+=$10; array[NR,1]=$11; array[NR,2]=$10; next;} END {

  for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    printf "%3.0f'\.' %s \b '\-' %s \b '\-' %3.1f'\%' \n", i, array[i,1], array[i,2], array[i,2]/sum*100
 }'
```

All code C:

```
#include <unistd.h>

struct command
{
  const char **argv;
};

int
spawn_proc (int in, int out, struct command *cmd)
{
  pid_t pid;

  if ((pid = fork ()) == 0)
    {
      if (in != 0)
        {
          dup2 (in, 0);
          close (in);
        }

      if (out != 1)
        {
          dup2 (out, 1);
          close (out);
        }

      return execvp (cmd->argv [0], (char * const *)cmd->argv);
    }

  return pid;
}

int
fork_pipes (int n, struct command *cmd)
{
  int i;
  pid_t pid;
  int in, fd [2];

  /* The first process should get its input from the original file descriptor 0.  */
  in = 0;

  /* Note the loop bound, we spawn here all, but the last stage of the pipeline.  */
  for (i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i)
    {
      pipe (fd);

      /* f [1] is the write end of the pipe, we carry `in` from the prev iteration.  */
      spawn_proc (in, fd [1], cmd + i);

      /* No need for the write and of the pipe, the child will write here.  */
      close (fd [1]);

      /* Keep the read end of the pipe, the next child will read from there.  */
      in = fd [0];
    }

  /* Last stage of the pipeline - set stdin be the read end of the previous pipe
     and output to the original file descriptor 1. */  
  if (in != 0)
    dup2 (in, 0);

  /* Execute the last stage with the current process. */
  return execvp (cmd [i].argv [0], (char * const *)cmd [i].argv);
}

int
main ()
{
    const char *sort[] = { "sort", "-t", " ", "-k", "10", "-r", "-n", "log.txt", 0 };
    const char *head[] = { "head", "-n 10", 0 };
    const char *awk[] = {  "awk", "{sum+=$10; array[NR,1]=$11; array[NR,2]=$10; next;} END { code there }", 0 };

   struct command cmd [] = { {sort}, {head}, {awk} };

  return fork_pipes (3, cmd);
}
```

Comment: The question is unclear.  Please state the question in the title, and at the end of your post.  It's really hard to answer if we don't understand...

Comment: I need add to  const char *awk[] = '{sum+=$10; array[NR,1]=$11; array[NR,2]=$10; next;} END {

  for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
  printf "%3.0f'\.' %s \b '\-' %s \b '\-' %3.1f'\%' \n", i, array[i,1], array[i,2], array[i,2]/sum*100
 }'

Comment: I am edit. See task on the top.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't know how to create the `awk` command string in C:

You can just put your `awk` program inline, but you have to escape all your quotes and backslashes; 
Note: you can break that string into multiple lines (at least in C++, so I assume in C too):

```
const char* awk = "... END { "
  "printf(\"%3.0f'\\.' %s \\b '\\-' %s \\b"
  " '\\-' %3.1f'\\%' \\n\" "
  "}";
```

Comment: awk: warning: escape sequence `\.' treated as plain `.'
awk: warning: escape sequence `\-' treated as plain `-'
awk: warning: escape sequence `\%' treated as plain `%'
awk: {sum+=$10; array[NR,1]=$11; array[NR,2]=$10; next;} END { printf("%3.0f'\.' %s \b '\-' %s \b '\-' %3.1f'\%' \n" }
awk:                                                                                                                 ^ syntax error